# Translating between DRF's serializer and model design

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to support the use of Annotator.JS(http://annotatorjs.org/) in the frontend of my web application. The problem is the model I use to store any annotations that a user makes is different to the JSON that Annotator.JS sends from the front end in an AJAX request.

The structure of Annotator.JS' JSON is:

```
{
  "id": "39fc339cf058bd22176771b3e3187329",  # unique id (added by backend)
  "annotator_schema_version": "v1.0",        # schema version: default v1.0
  "created": "2011-05-24T18:52:08.036814",   # created datetime in iso8601 format (added by backend)
  "updated": "2011-05-26T12:17:05.012544",   # updated datetime in iso8601 format (added by backend)
  "text": "A note I wrote",                  # content of annotation
  "quote": "the text that was annotated",    # the annotated text (added by frontend)
  "uri": "http://example.com",               # URI of annotated document (added by frontend)
  "ranges": [                                # list of ranges covered by annotation (usually only one entry)
    {
      "start": "/p[69]/span/span",           # (relative) XPath to start element
      "end": "/p[70]/span/span",             # (relative) XPath to end element
      "startOffset": 0,                      # character offset within start element
      "endOffset": 120                       # character offset within end element
    }
  ],
  "user": "alice",                           # user id of annotation owner (can also be an object with an 'id' property)
  "consumer": "annotateit",                  # consumer key of backend
  "tags": [ "review", "error" ],             # list of tags (from Tags plugin)
}
```

The structure of my Annotation model is:

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    datapoint = models.ForeignKey('datapoint.Datapoint', related_name='%(class)s_parent_datapoint_relation')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.User', related_name='%(class)s_creator_relation')

    # Key fields from the Annotator JSON Format: http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/latest/annotation-format.html
    annotator_schema_version = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    quote = models.TextField()
    uri = models.URLField(blank=True)
    range_start = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    range_end = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    range_startOffset = models.BigIntegerField()
    range_endOffset = models.BigIntegerField()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

How can I create a serializer that can translate from the model structure to the JSON?

P.S. Annotator.JS allows the user to send extra information with the JSON structure noted above so the fact that Datapoint isn't included in the JSON structure isn't an issue. This can be passed along without any problem. Owner would hopefully equal User in the JSON.

Thanks for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just using a default ModelSerializer should get you serialization for all the simple fields for free (version, text, quote, uri), just by specifying which fields you want serialized. The other fields look straightforward as well:

- To compose the ranges object, you can use a SerializerMethodField which lets you define a custom serializer method (return an array of dictionaries containing values from the range_* attributes on your model). Note that if you also need to be able to deserialize JSON into your model you'll need to define custom fields.
- To go from owner -> user_id SlugRelatedField (assuming you can access the user id you want from the User object)
- You can also use SlugRelatedField to go from TaggableManager -> ["tag", "values"] (again, assuming you can access the value you want through the model object managed by TaggableManager.

In general, everything you want is described in pretty good detail in the documentation.

Comment: To address the ranges object:
I need to deserialise JSON as well, therefore custom fields. Is this one for each part of ranges array that are then referred to in another range field?

Comment: I think in your case it may be better to define a Range object (normal python class, not a django model) which has the fields you want and create a serializer for it that can handle serialization (Annotation -> Range object json) and deserialization (Range object json -> Range object) as well as any validation you want. Include this as a field in your Annotation model serializer (nested serializer). Then you can override the Annotation serializer's save() method where you'll have access to all the Range object fields to do whatever you want with.